# Bottom Sheet dialog fragment doesn't see fragment result api values

Tags: android, fragment

i have 2 fragments: base and bottomSheet.

in my main fragment i have:

```
parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult(
            WEATHER_RESPONSE_KEY,
            bundleOf(WEATHER_RESPONSE_KEY to newValue)
        )
```

i start bottomSheet this way:

```
InfoBottomSheetFragment.newInstance()
                    .show(
                        parentFragmentManager,
                        InfoBottomSheetFragment.TAG
                    )
```

and in BS fragment i'm subscribing to changes in onCreateView like this:

```
parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(WeatherFragment.WEATHER_RESPONSE_KEY,viewLifecycleOwner){_,bundle->
            weatherResponse = bundle.getSerializable(WeatherFragment.WEATHER_RESPONSE_KEY) as WeatherResponse
        }
```

so the problem is that my weatherResponse is null, but it shouldn't be, because it's not null when i set it to setFragmentResult